# capture image clicked in one page and display the same in another page HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Newbie to HTML...creating a custom furniture website with custom design tab which helps in designing your own furniture..now i wanted to capture the image clicked(out of many) by user in my main.html page and display the selected image in secondary.html page when the user navigates to second page to select the color for the sofa...Need help!

**main.html**

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue">4 Seater <img  src="images/4_Seater_Default.jpg" alt="4_Seater_Default.jpg"  onclick="showImage('4_Seater_Default.jpg');" /></a></div>
    <div class="blue">3 Seater<img  src="images/3_Seater_Default.jpg" alt="3_Seater_Default.jpg"  onclick="showImage('3_Seater_Default.jpg');" /></a></div>
    <div class="blue">2 Seater<img  src="images/2_Seater_Default.jpg" alt="2_Seater_Default.jpg"  onclick="showImage('2_Seater_Default.jpg');" /></a></div>
    <div class="blue">1 Seater<img  src="images/1_Seater_Default.jpg" alt="1_Seater_Default.jpg"  onclick="showImage('1_Seater_Default.jpg');" /></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page 1:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Page 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function filename(){
     var fullPath = document.getElementById("image").src;
     var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
     var fileid = filename.split("\.")[0];;
     window.location.href = "test2.jsp?imgid="+fileid;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<IMG id="image" SRC="images/1.png" width="100px" alt="Logo" onclick="filename();">
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Page 2</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var imageId = location.search.split('imgid=')[1];
document.getElementById('image').src = "images/"+imageId+".png";    \\it will set the value of the img src to 1.png which is passed from the previous page
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<IMG id="image" SRC="images/2.png" width="400px">
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

In Page1 onclick event we are simply calling the `filename()` function. This function in turn is appending the imageId in the url of the second page. Now, when you land on the second page, the `$(document).ready(function(){})` is taking the imageId from the url and setting the `SRC` of the `<IMG>` tag with the image `1.png`.

Comment: Hi Leo..how can i pass the 'onclick' function in displayed <img id = "image"? in page2.html ....thanks in advance.

Comment: NARENH...please refer to the edit section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
function showImage(imagePath){

window.location.href= "www.yourdomain.com/yourDirectory/path/showImage?image_path="+imagePath;
}
```

and on the above url you can use this path to show image + any other content, whatever is required.

Comment: can u explain as to where to place this code and use the var +imagePath in ?

Comment: This code is nothing but a javascript function that you can add in script block in your html page.  As you have added a onclick function on image, it is a handler for the same